# Access Other component variable/states

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I want to access state data or Portfolio in TotalTab/ProfitTab/LossesTab. I want them to get the data updated ( get data bind ? ) when async fetchData is finish also.

My code is as below

```jsx
class Portfolio extends Component{

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            isLoading: true,
            dataSource : ""
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() { //This function get called once when react finished loading. Something like jQueryDom Ready seems to be https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/tutorial.html
       this.fetchData();
    }

    fetchData() {
        fetch("http://beta.setmonitor.com/api/trading/summary?portfolio_id=3")
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((responseData) => {
            this.setState({
               dataSource: responseData,
               isLoading: false
            });
        })
        .done();
    }

    render() {
        return (
          <ScrollableTabView>
            <TotalTab tabLabel="Total" />
            <ProfitTab tabLabel="Profit" />
            <LossesTab tabLabel="Losses" />
          </ScrollableTabView>
        );
    }
};
```

I tried creating an another class for just fetching data and storing and use it like `new ClassName` but the problem is that async data don't get update in the view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Utilize props. You can pass the data down to the `Tab` components and React will automatically keep it in sync. If needed, you can also declare a function in the `Portfolio` component and pass that down to the children as needed. 
[React Docs - Data Flow](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/multiple-components.html#data-flow)

Comment: Thanks a lot , thats what I needed :)